# Unity Keystore key creation Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, keystore, publishing

I am having an issue creating a Unity Key store key.

Am running unity 2021.2.3f1 personal.

What I have tried is go to Edit>Project Settings>Player>Publishing Settings>Key store Manager>Create New>anywhere>Save key name>Fill in the data ------> but when I click on "add key:, it just doesn't do anything.

am I doing something wrong?

is there a way to create it somewhere else and then import it to unity?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had same issue and just resolved.

I was able to create a keystore after downloading some module my version of unity editor.

try to add Android build supprot/ android SDK&NDK tools

should work